# Button is clickable but Api does not work then how can I verify that in the playwright automation

Tags: playwright

Actually i'm working on one of the project where 'CSV download' button is working but api is not called so my question is >> How can i verify that when i click on the 'CSV download' button and CSV is downloaded.

I'm creating automation script with playwright where i have to expect that 'Download CSV' button is working or not

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how the download is triggered (via API, or static js on the page)- you can leverage the [download](https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads) event to catch the CSV being
downloaded. Here is an example:

```js
// Start waiting for download before clicking. Note no await.
const downloadPromise = page.waitForEvent('download');
// Trigger download
await page.getByText('CSV download').click();
// Wait for the download process to complete
const download = await downloadPromise;
const tempPath = await download.path();
// Check it is a csv
expect(tempPath.endsWith('.csv')).toBeTruthy();
```